# Regex: How to remove FQN

Tags: regex

I want to remove the domain information from hostnames.
E.g. I want `"server1.mydomain.com"` to be just `"server1"`.
I thought I had it with:

```
^(\w*)
```

But then I realized I also have hostnames like `"desktop-1.mydomain.com"`, and they all got changed to `"desktop"` and not `"desktop-1"` etc.
Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Try `^[^.]+` to match up to the first dot.

Comment: Excellent! And really fast answer! Thanks a lot, fantastic first experience at this site:) I do not understand how I can mark this as the solution, though.

Comment: @kodax There is a check on the left side of the answer (under the number of votes). You can click on it in order to mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by Wiktor in the comments, the easiest regular expression is

```
^[^.]+
```

The explanation from [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) is:

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
Match a single character not present in the list below [^.]+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as 
possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
```

If you are using a programming language, another possible solution is to split the string in the dot character and get the first element of the resulting array. For example:

```
const array1 = 'server1.mydomain.com'.split(/\./);
console.log(array1[0]);

const array2 = 'desktop-1.mydomain.com'.split(/\./);
console.log(array2[0]);
```

Prints:

```
server1
desktop-1
```

Comment: Thank you also! Impressive knowledge here:)